# 1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)"

Tags: python, mysql, database

Working on a simple python application which is allowing user to sign up and record the user information in mysql db but I am continuously getting this weird error

```
> MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user
> 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")  * Detected change in
> '/Users/xxxxx/Documents/GitHub/MySQL-and-Python-master/FlaskApp/app.py',
> reloading
```

1. I have already changed from root user to a new user and password is reset as well
2. Already gone through plenty of posts on the similar error and tried multiple different options but no luck
3. Code sample:

```py
    
    

        from flask import Flask, render_template, json, request, redirect,
            session from flask_mysqldb import MySQL import mysql.connector
               
            # from flask.ext.mysql import MySQL
            # from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
            >   
            >   app = Flask(__name__)
            >   
            >   mysql = MySQL()
        
        >   
    # MySQL configurations app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'testuser1' app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'password123'
    >   app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'MyDB'
    >   app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
    >   
    >   print() mysql.init_app(app)
    >   
    >   # set a secret key for the session app.secret_key = 'why would I tell you my secret key?'
    >     
    >
    
         
        >     @app.route("/")
        >     def main():
        >         return render_template('index.html')
        >     
        >     
        >     @app.route('/showSignUp')
        >     def showSignUp():
        >         return render_template('signup.html')
        >     
        >     
        >     @app.route('/signUp', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
        >     def signUp():
        >         # read the posted values from the UI
        >         _name = request.form['inputName']
        >         _email = request.form['inputEmail']
        >         _password = request.form['inputPassword']
        >     
        >         print("Name", _name)
        >         print("Email", _email)
        >         print("password", _password)
        >     
        >         # validate the received values
        >         if _name and _email and _password:
        >             conn = mysql.connect()
        >             cursor = conn.cursor()
        >     
        >             # _hash_password = generate_password_hash(_password)
        >     
        >             cursor.callproc('sp_createUser', (_name, _email, _password))

It is not clear to me why it is picking up root as the user where I am clearly giving testuser. Any pointers will be hugely helpful.
```

Comment: I think you have to  use a password to login

Comment: I am using the correct password already.. I thought, this is going to be pretty quick but just connecting to the db is becoming a pain